# Does Minecraft ever care about NBT Lists vs Arrays?

Tags: minecraft

As you know, Minecraft uses the [NBT Format](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/NBT_format) to store data. The format defines several types, some of which are :

- List : Stores a list of any specified other type
- Byte Array : Stores a list of **bytes** specifically
- Int Array : Stores a list of **int** (32 bit) specifically
- Long Array : Stores a list of **long** (64 bit) specifically

My question is, does the difference between a Byte Array and a List of Bytes actually matter in practice ? If I used lists everywhere, would it break anything ?

I'm implementing an NBT encoder / decoder for the second time, and I really want to throw away arrays. They only save a single byte each, and are simply redundant ; plus keeping track of what should be stored as which is a bigger architectural annoyance than it may seem.

Comment: In the end you'll be converting to either byte arrays or writing all of the bytes in the list sequentially anyhow. For a lower-level interface, it's best to stick with what you really have, in this case byte arrays.

Comment: @Rogue I’m not sure I understand what you mean. Here the only difference is the byte array as a 5 byte header, and the list of bytes has a 6 bytes header. After that they contain the exact same data, sequential bytes.

Answer (score -1):

For of the time, even if int are used, the Long Array is used. It's what I can remember of all my NBT management.

In general, you can check [wiki.vg](https://wiki.vg/Main_Page) website that show lot of informations about MC protocol and formatting.

Comment: That case is not problematic, the real problem is having to differentiate Lists and Arrays of the same type, because they correspond to the same thing in the language I’m using (swift).

Comment: Thanks a **lot** for this link, seems like a very helpful resource ! I will definitely be using it for a few things.